# Structure of my program is incorrect Newbie

Tags: vba

I have a program here im working on for myself at work, i work as a Programmer for CNC machines. i'm just trying to make something that helps with various things i have to look up all the time to figure out.

basically we machine threads sometimes, and when doing so theres alot of data to take into account. this would ask what size thread along with the pitch of the thread, then output all the correlating data to its respective textbox.

Below is the code i have. i have errors on the 4 lines right after "Public Sub Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click"

```
Public Class Form1
Dim num1 As Decimal
Dim num2 As Decimal
Dim Major As Double
Dim TPI As Double
Dim Minor As Double
Dim STH As Double
Dim P As Double
Dim VD As Double
Dim WS As Double
Dim OW As Double



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    num1 = CDec(MCBox1.Text)
    MCBox1.Text = num1
    num2 = CDec(num1 * 0.03937)
    MCBox2.Text = num2.ToString

End Sub

Public Sub Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click

    STH = (0.75 * P)(Math.Cos(30))
    VD = Major - 1.75(TPI)(Math.Cos(30))
    WS = TPI(Math.Tan(30))
    OW = (3 * BWS) + VD

    Maj.Text = Major
    Min.Text = Major - 2 * STH
    Pitch.Text = Major - STH
    BWS.Text = WS
    MOW.Text = OW
    ThreadHeight.Text = STH
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: *"i have errors on the 4 lines right after"* - Please specify the line(s) of code and the error(s) you're seeing, as well as what about those errors is unclear and the result of what efforts you've made so far to correct them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use intuitive math expressions in code.  For example, this:

```
1.75(TPI)
```

This is telling the code that you think `1.75` is *a function* that you're trying to invoke.  It isn't.  If you're trying to multiply, you have to use the right operator for that (just like you already do elsewhere):

```
1.75 * TPI
```

There are a few other lines where you're doing the same thing, so this will have to be corrected there as well.  Also keep in mind order of operations for your operators to make sure you're getting the result you expect.

Comment: so would (1.75 * TPI) work? basically put the whole thing in parentheses would work as well correct?

Comment: @Jfisher387: That would work to multiply those two values, yes.  Continue that pattern for additional math operations throughout the code.